# Doubts about [dcl.spec]/3 in c++1z

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, declaration, c++17

[[dcl.spec]/3 in c++1z](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec#3) (emphasis is mine):

> If a *type-name* is encountered while parsing a *decl-specifier-seq*,
>   it is interpreted as part of the *decl-specifier-seq* if and only if
>   there is no previous *defining-type-specifier* other than a
>   *cv-qualifier* in the *decl-specifier-seq*. The sequence shall be self-consistent as described below. [ Example:
>
> ```
> typedef char* Pc;
> static Pc;                      // error: name missing
> ```
>
> Here, the declaration `static Pc` is ill-formed because no name was
>   specified for the static variable of type `Pc`. **To get a variable
>   called `Pc`, a *type-specifier* (other than `const` or `volatile`) has
>   to be present to indicate that the *typedef-name* `Pc` is the name
>   being (re)declared, rather than being part of the `decl-specifier`
>   sequence**.

Nevertheless, the snippet below doesn't compile in g++ and clang. Why is that?

```
typedef char* Pc;
static int Pc;
```

Comment: It is a draft. Implementation of drafts is always experimental in compilers and on whatever-they-fill-the-most-important-priority basis. Apparently, an option to redefine typedefs is not considered urgent - the notion which I share in full.

Comment: @SergeyA The paragraph is present in C++14 and C++11 as [dcl.spec]/2

Comment: Notice that the quoted text doesn't make the claim that you're allowed to put `static int Pc` in the same declarative region. It would be fine, though, if you placed it in a more nested declarative region.

Answer (score 3):

The intent of the paragraph is to show that `typedef char* Pc` is valid, whereas `static Pc` is not, *not* that you can redeclare `Pc` as something else (in the same scope). In other words, `static Pc` and `static int Pc` are not different entities. Nothing's changed that would allow you to do this.

[[basic.scope.declarative]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope#basic.scope.declarative-4)

> Given a set of declarations in a single declarative region, each of
>   which specifies the same unqualified name,
>
> (4.1) — they shall all refer to the same entity, ...

Comment: But this compiles in g++ and clang. Note that `A` is not the same entity in the two declarations below:
`struct A{};
A a;
int A;`

Comment: @JohnKalane The next point says: "exactly one declaration shall declare a class name or enumeration name that is not a typedef name and the other declarations shall all refer to the same variable, non-static data member, or enumerator, or all refer to functions and function templates; in this case the class name or enumeration name is hidden ..." In other words, shadowing is in effect.

Comment: `The intent of the paragraph is to show that typedef char* Pc is valid, whereas static Pc is not, not that you can redeclare Pc as something else (in the same scope).` But the highlighted phrase in [dcl.spec]/3 above seems to say exactly the opposite of what you're saying here.

Comment: @JohnKalane `static Pc` is a syntax error, period. In other words, `typedef` doesn't allow you to omit the `type-specifier`, in this case `int`.

Comment: I was referring to the part in bold characters highlighted above in [dcl.spec]/3.